# Manipulate - mechanics

Tags: manipulate

I have a simple manipulation with points & lines:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Rotate[{
 Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {(a + b)/2, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{(a + b)/2, 0}]}, r, {0, 0}],
 Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {(a + b)/2, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{(a + b)/2, 0}]}, -r, {0, 0}],
 Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {-a, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{-a, 0}]}, r, {0, 0}],
 Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {-b, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{-b, 0}]}, -r, {0, 0}]
 }, q, {0, 0}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], 
{{r, Pi/8}, 0, Pi/2}, {{q, 0}, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {{a, 1}, 0, 1.5}, {{b, 1}, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there any way of getting and using the coordinates of the end-points while they are being manipulated (other than work out their trig relationships ... I anticipate there will be quite a few)?

Comment: rewrite this with `RotationTransform`.

Comment: @Kuba will this approach work if I have lots of rotations within rotations?

Comment: @martin: Your rotations are simple rotations about the origin, so a composition of two rotations is just a rotation by the sum of the angles of the individual rotations.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus the intention is to have lines rotating about the endpoints too ... things could get a little complicated

Comment: @martin `Manipulate[
 r1 = RotationTransform[q];
 r2 = RotationTransform[r];
 r3 = RotationTransform[-r];
 pkt2 = r1 /@ MapThread[Compose, {{r2, r3, r2, r3}, pkt}];
 Grid[{{
    Graphics[{
      Thick, AbsolutePointSize@7,
      {Point[#], Line[{{0, 0}, #}]} & /@ pkt2
      }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
    Column@pkt2
    }}],
 {{r, Pi/8}, 0, Pi/2},
 {{q, 0}, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 {{a, 1}, 0, 1.5},
 {{b, 1}, 0, 1.5},
 Initialization :> (
   pkt := {{(a + b)/2, 0}, {(a + b)/2, 0}, {-a, 0}, {-b, 0}}
   ),
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, r, q}]`

Comment: @Kuba thank you - will give that a go now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kuba mentioned, you can quite easily work out the trig relations to give the endpoints directly, using `RotationTransform`:

```
RotationTransform[q] /@ {RotationTransform[r]@{(a + b)/2, 0}, 
  RotationTransform[-r]@{(a + b)/2, 0}, RotationTransform[r]@{-a, 0}, 
  RotationTransform[-r]@{-b, 0}}
```

which produces the coordinates of the red dots:

```
{{1/2 (a + b) Cos[q] Cos[r] - 1/2 (a + b) Sin[q] Sin[r], 
  1/2 (a + b) Cos[r] Sin[q] + 
   1/2 (a + b) Cos[q] Sin[r]}, {1/2 (a + b) Cos[q] Cos[r] + 
   1/2 (a + b) Sin[q] Sin[r], 
  1/2 (a + b) Cos[r] Sin[q] - 
   1/2 (a + b) Cos[q] Sin[r]}, {-a Cos[q] Cos[r] + 
   a Sin[q] Sin[r], -a Cos[r] Sin[q] - 
   a Cos[q] Sin[r]}, {-b Cos[q] Cos[r] - 
   b Sin[q] Sin[r], -b Cos[r] Sin[q] + b Cos[q] Sin[r]}}
```

Similarly, you can add the numerical coordinates to your `Manipulate` object:

```
Manipulate[{MatrixForm[
   RotationTransform[q] /@ {RotationTransform[r]@{(a + b)/2, 0}, 
     RotationTransform[-r]@{(a + b)/2, 0}, 
     RotationTransform[r]@{-a, 0}, RotationTransform[-r]@{-b, 0}}], 
  Graphics[{Rotate[{Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {(a + b)/2, 0}}], Red, 
        PointSize[Large], Point[{(a + b)/2, 0}]}, r, {0, 0}], 
      Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {(a + b)/2, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[{(a + b)/2, 0}]}, -r, {0, 0}], 
      Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {-a, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[{-a, 0}]}, r, {0, 0}], 
      Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {-b, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[{-b, 0}]}, -r, {0, 0}]}, q, {0, 0}]}, Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 500]}, {{r, Pi/8}, 0,
   Pi/2}, {{q, 0}, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {{a, 1}, 0, 1.5}, {{b, 1}, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just about to go about it the old fashioned way with trig ..